# Digital Stethoscope

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier

I am trying to make a digital stethoscope. I have attached a condenser mic on the end of stethoscope. Mic Signal is fed to a pre-amp circuit made through TL072 IC. I've attached the schematic.[This](http://www.radiolocman.com/shem/schematics.html?di=64243) is the circuit of electronic stethoscope i am re-making. I am using +9V and -9V to power the IC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMfTMG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On Arduino (Due) I've attached a TFT LCD on which i am observing the incoming waveform. Problem is I can't see good heart beat waveform. I can see the change in waveform when i tap the diaphragm of stethoscope with my finger or talk near the diaphragm.
I am also attaching the current heart beat waveform i am receiving. [image]

Comment: Call a doctor! Now!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. What is your question? (Edit your question rather than comment.) Also, is this your own circuit or someone elses? Link?

Comment: What supply voltages are you using for the op amps? (Again, please edit your question.)

Comment: Is the microphone inside a stethoscope acoustic structure? Is it rated for low bandwidth? Do you know, what to expect from the stethoscope?

Comment: @BrianDrummond - Too late for a doctor, it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have enough gain in the circuit.

The one you linked to has an LM386 to drive an earphone, and it als has a separate 741 to drive an LED.  Both of those provide extra gain.

The LM386 has gain of 20, and the 741 circuit has a gain of 71.

Most likely, you need another opamp stage to boost the gain.

I wouldn't try to increase the gain of OA1.  I'd just add another opamp after OA2, and give it a gain of 20.

If you were using a 16Bit ADC instead of the Arduino 10Bit ADC, you wouldn't really need any additional gain - what you've got would be adequately sampled at 16Bits.

---

One last thing to consider is how you couple the microphone to your chest.

I find in my experiments that a simple [plastic pipe end cap](https://www.stockcap.com/store/end-caps.html) can be used to improve pickup.  You can get them at any hardware store for less than a dollar a piece.  The ones I use are about 2 inches (5cm) diameter.

I just drill a hole in the cap that is a smidge smaller than the diameter of the microphone capsule and press the mic capsule into the hole.  The hole can be on the side or the top - it doesn't really matter.

Another thing I find helpful is to use a cardioid microphone rather than an omnidirectional.  The cardioid mics have an opening in the back behind the membrane.  With the forward opening inside the pipe cap, and the backside opening outside the cap, all pressure changes inside the cap can impart their full power to the membrane.  This gets you a stronger signal.

Try putting the microphone in an end cap first, and maybe replace the mic with a cardioid one.  If that doesn't make enough difference, add another opamp stage for some extra gain.

---

Another thing you might try is oversampling.  The arduino samples at 10K samples per second.  If you read 16 values and add them up, you will gain the equivalent of 2 bits of resolution - instead of 1023 steps, you have 4096.  Oversampling at that rate still gives you an effective sampling rate of 625 samples per second, which is more than adequate for the audio spectrum you need to pick up heart beats.

Since you are using the Due, you could activate the 12Bit ADC mode and see if that helps.

---

A final suggestion:
Consider changing the Aref input to the Arduino.  The standard value is 5Volts.  Changing it to 1Volt is a gain of 5.  That gives you 1mV steps instead of 5mV steps.

Combine all of the above tricks, and you may well be able to skip adding an extra opamp for more gain.

Comment: I am using Arduino Due which has 12 bit ADC. Will that help be of any help?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  Switch to 12Bit (that's a separate initialization step) and that will help.  The digitized data will represent smaller values, but you can multiply the digital values to make them more visible on screen.

Comment: 16X oversampling would get you to the equivalent of a 14Bit ADC when using the 12Bit ADC of the Due.  That's a resolution of 16384 steps, or about 0.3mV when using the standard 5V Aref.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is that the acoustic signal from lungs is too weak to be detected. Another reason is bad acoustic coupling between the stethoscope and microphone.

I suggest checking the microphone signal on a professional amplifier like audio mixer.

Comment: Your lungs pump blood?  Did you maybe mean "acoustic signal from the heart?"